# Testing Web Apps in different Mobiles and profiling tool for mobiles

Tags: html, testing, mobile

I am developing a RWD web app supporting from mobile to desktop. I need to test the web app in different mobiles ranging from iPhone, android phone and BB phone and Windows phone, iPad and android tablets and desktops.

Currently i am doing testing using the chrome web browser and i squeeze the browser window to see the behavior in different width screen.

Is there any better approach available to do the testing in different versions of phones? and is there any tool available to test the loading time in mobiles, i know profiling tools like fiddler is available for desktop, is any profiling tool available for mobile also?

Please help me in this. thanks in advance for any help.